# Disable button in Java until all fields filled

Tags: java, button, netbeans

I'm new to Java and developing a small project. I'm making a program where the **user** has to **register** themselves. I have 3 different tabs on my Tabbed Pane. I want to be able to **disable** the **next button** on the **first** pane making it impossible for the **user** to **continue** to pane 2 unless all the `text` fields on pane 1 have been **filled**. I have been Searching online and found various examples but none of them would work in run time.

I am using Netbeans.

```
  private void txtFirstNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    if(txtFirstName.getText().trim().length() > 0)

        btnNext1.setEnabled(true);
    else 
        btnNext1.setEnabled(false); 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `List` of all the text fields on your pane:

```
List<JTextField> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add all your text fields to that list.

Then, create a universal `DocumentListener` that listens for text change events, and every time a text update happens, scan through all your text fields to see if they have all been filled:

```
DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() {
    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { changedUpdate(e); }
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { changedUpdate(e); }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        boolean canEnable = true;
        for (JTextField tf : list) {
            if (tf.getText().isEmpty()) {
                canEnable = false;
            }
        }
        btnNext1.setEnabled(canEnable);
    }
};
```

And add that `listener` to every text field you have in the list:

```
for (JTextField tf : list) {
    tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(piecesListener);
}
```